# EFCore Bulkextension's BulkInsertAsync not setting the id (identity field)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert, efcore.bulkextensions

EFCore Bulkextension's BulkInsertAsync  not setting the id (identity field).

we are using EFCore.BulkExtensions version 6.3.3
and as per [this](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/612) link this issue is fixed in v5.3.7.
Anyone aware about whether it is really fixed or am I missing anything here ?
We are getting negative id in result variable the below code:

```
public async Task InsertAsync(List<User> users)
{
     BulkConfig bulkCOnfig = new BulkConfig()
     {       
       SetOutputIdentity = true
     };
     await this.BulkInsertAsync(users, bulkCOnfig);

     var result = users.FirstOrDefault().Id;
}
```

But if I use BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync then I'm getting Ids all records except the last one.

Comment: Do you have triggers on the table?

Comment: no, don't have triggers on the table

Comment: I think the change tracker is disabled when you use this package. To get the Ids, you need to retrieve the entities from the database

Comment: @AnandSonake, code which do the trick via `Merge` exists. Why it is not working is another question. Better to just debug. Source code is simple.

Comment: You didn't post any code that retrieves the new IDs. The project you're using isn't part of EF Core. Are you sure it updates the objects it inserts?

Comment: If that extension uses SqlBulkCopy to perform an actual minimally-logged BULK INSERT operation there's no way to return IDs or any other kind of result. EF Core itself isn't tracking the objects. If it did, it would both INSERT them and update them with the new IDs when `SaveChanges` was called. The operations would be batched using MERGE whose `OUTPUT` clause would return the IDs. That wouldn't be as fast as a BULK INSERT operation though

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it looks like [that extension inserts into a temporary table then uses MERGE](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/EFCore.BulkExtensions/DbContextBulkTransaction.cs#L58).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have examined the same thing. Yes i have analyzed sources. Code too ugly to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try **EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT**:

GitHub: https://github.com/videokojot/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT/

It is MIT fork of *EFCore.BulkExtensions*, I fixed there multiple issues regrading setting the output idenity, so maybe your issue is fixed there.

This fork fixes issues not fixed in original:

- [Fix Insert New Only](https://github.com/videokojot/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT/issues/45)
- [Fix Output Identity not set when column is null](https://github.com/videokojot/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT/issues/46)
- [Output Identity not set when db columns are not unique](https://github.com/videokojot/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT/issues/48)
- [entitiesWithOutputIdentity contains the ids rather than the entities](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/1297)

Choose major version (6.x/7.x/8.x) based on EFCore version you are using (actual code and fixes are shared).

I also refactored and cleaned the project, so the anyone can simply checkout and run tests locally.

I added the tests for BulkInsertAsync and they all pass:
https://github.com/videokojot/EFCore.BulkExtensions.MIT/pull/70/files

If you can give me reproduction scenario, the fix will be probably easy.

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of this MIT fork.*